# Angular2: how to manipulate url query string?

Tags: angular

in angular 1 there is a `$location.search()` function which can manipulate URL query string. What is the angular2 equivalent?

I tried

```
import {Location} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

and

```
import {URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short Answer (in TypeScript):

```
// Import you were looking for
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http';
//... jump down some code
export class MyRegistrationsComponent {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getDudesAndDudettes() {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers,
            // Have to make a URLSearchParams with a query string
            search: new URLSearchParams('firstName=John&lastName=Smith}')
        });

        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/MyEventsAPI', options)
            .map(res => <Dudes[]>res.json().data)
  }
```

The docs can be found at [Angular2 API Docs for RequestOptions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html). You will notice that the `search` param is a type of [`URLSearchParams`](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/URLSearchParams-class.html)

Another example is in the [Angular2 Guides](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#search-parameters) (don't mind the JSONP stuff, it's generally how to use query parameters for normal http requests too).

Reference to explain it a different way:  [How to utilise URLSearchParams in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386367/how-to-utilise-urlsearchparams-in-angular-2/34413223#34413223)

Also, if you didn't import [RxJS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#rxjs) in your `app.ts` observable functionality will break.

More Complete Example in TypeScript:

```
import {Component}      from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http';
import {Registrant}     from './registrant';
import {Registration}   from './registration';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-registrations',
    templateUrl: 'app/my-registrations.component.html',
    inputs: ['registrant']
})

export class MyRegistrationsComponent {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private _registrantionsUrl: string = 'http://localhost:3000/MyEventsAPI';
    private _title = 'My Registrations Search';
    public registrant: Registrant = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" };

    findMyEvents() {
        let body = JSON.stringify(this.registrant);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers,
            search: new URLSearchParams(`firstName=${this.registrant.firstName}&lastName=${this.registrant.lastName}`)
        });

        return this.http.get(this._registrantionsUrl, options)
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => <Registration[]>res.json().data)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }

}
```

Comment: It is a good example for xhr request. But it sends a request to a rest api server. What i need is only to modify parameters on the address bar without  making an xhr request.

Comment: @vbilici so inside a function, like `findMyEvents() { window.location.replace(\`http://my.current.page.com?firstName=${this.registrant.firstName}&lastName=${this.registrant.lastName}\`); }` Is that more of what you are looking for

Comment: @Toolkit it's a dumpster fire for sure, or drinking from a fire hydrant. Pick your metaphor. :) Programming is finding better ways to solve challenging and common problems. The frontend folks just have a lot of opinions on the matter, https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'start'
})
@View({
  template: `<h1>{{name}}</h1>`
})
export class Start {
  name: string;

    constructor(routeParams: RouteParams){
        this.name = 'Start' + routeParams.get('x');
    }
}
```

Comment: and where do I find RouteParams? Including the relevant import and additional js files would be useful here.

Comment: RouteParams are deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Do you use typescript ? If so, you might need to reference the d.ts file containing the typings for angular2 with the following code :

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
```

I did a little project where I had this problem, webstorm wouldn't find anything from angular2, and highlight my imports as errors. Including this line of code before importing from angular2 solved it.