# How to utilise URLSearchParams in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I've been hours now trying to figure out how to correctly inject the `URLSearchParams` dependency into a component.

In my `boot.ts` I'm making sure to include `HTTP_PROVIDERS` - I'm honestly not even sure it's required for `URLSearchParams`.

I've also ensured that I'm including the http bundle script in my page.

***boot.ts***

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}),
  PanelsService,
  FiltersService
])
```

It is `FiltersService` where I'm attempting to inject `URLSearchParams`.

***filter.service.ts***

```
import {Component, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class FiltersService {

  constructor(private _searchParams:URLSearchParams) { }

  setFilter(name, value) {
    this._searchParams.set(name, value);
  }

  getFilter(name) {
    this._searchParams.get(name);
  }
}
```

Injecting `URLSearchParams` in the constructor causes the error:

[image]

I've read [this article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html), a couple of times in fact and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

For what it's worth, I encounter the same problem when attempting to inject `RouteParams`. I'm clearly missing something fundamental.

**EDIT**: For some more clarity, this is what my `StoriesComponent` looks like:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {PanelsService} from '../panels/panels.service';
import {RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';
import {FiltersService} from '../common/filters.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'stories',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/stories/stories.component.html'
})
export class StoriesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public panelsService:PanelsService,
    public filtersService: FiltersService,
    private _routeParams:RouteParams) {

    this.panelsService.setSelectedPanel(this._routeParams.params['panelId']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Stories');
  }

  addPanel() {
    var newPanel = {
      id: 999,
      name: 'my new panel name',
      time: 744
      // time: 168
    }

    this.panelsService.addPanel(newPanel);
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**: Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HhLMh7n8NLsx9oruNsjp?p=preview) which demonstrates my issue - see `peopleService.ts`

Comment: what is storiesComponent in your project ? i think problem is in the that class not in the filter.service check one again storiesComponent.

Comment: @PardeepJain I've updated my question with the contents of my `StoriesComponent`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So after a lot of research and help from Angular's Gitter, I've found out the answer to two of my problems.

Firstly, `URLSearchParams` cannot be injected in the constructor as a dependency like I'm trying to do - it can be `new`ed however.

`var params = new URLSearchParams()`

It also cannot be used as I was hoping it could be, which was to update the location. It appears to be simply a utility function for parsing query strings and setting query params which you can then use with `Router`'s `navigate` method.

Secondly, in order to access `RouteParams` it appears that your component needs to be instantiated by the `Router`, i.e. associating your component with a path in a `@RouteConfig` decorator.

This was not my case as I had a `<my-component></my-component>` in the shell of my application which was not instantiated by the `Router`.

This is my current understanding and hopefully this helps others with the same problem.

Comment: +1 for mentioning this fact - "Secondly, in order to access RouteParams it appears that your component needs to be instantiated by the Router, i.e. associating your component with a path in a @RouteConfig decorator."

Answer (score 1):

I made work the injection of `RouteParams` within Angular2 beta0. Which version do you use?

We simply need to specify route providers globally for your application as you did:

```
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
(...)
bootstrap(ApisparkApp, [
  (...)
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

Then simply import `RouteParams` where you want to use it and add it in the constructor of your component. Angular will give you the corresponding instance:

```
import { RouteParams } from 'angular2/router';

export class CompanyDetails implements OnInit {
  public company: Company;

  constructor(routeParams: RouteParams) {
    this.routeParams = routeParams;
  }
}
```

Since you specify it globally, you don't need to specify it again within the providers attribute of the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'company-details',
  providers: [ CompanyService ]
})
```

Otherwise, what do you exactly want to do with class `URLSearchParams`?

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I'm using `angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0`. When I do exactly what you've done above with `RouteParams` I get `No provider for RouteParams!`. The only place I can access `RouteParams` is in a component that is specified in my `@RouteConfig` decorator.

So this is problem 1. Problem 2 is injecting `URLSearchParams`. I want to access this in order to get and set parameters: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/URLSearchParams-class.html

Comment: Updated post with plunker example