# RouteParams on bootstrap of app?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, typescript1.7

I've got a simple angular 2 app seed. A simple bootstrap;

```
bootstrap(App, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

and App sets up a few routes;

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', component: Home, as: 'Home'},
    {path: '/login', component: Login, as: 'Login'}
])
```

Nothing fancy here. One of the things I do is OAuth2 login, which redirects away from the app, and then back, so what I wanted to do was pass in a query parameter on load. Something like `http://localhost/#?token=123` 
Based on the errors I keep getting, and this: [How to utilise URLSearchParams in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386367/how-to-utilise-urlsearchparams-in-angular-2) it seems I can't just inject `RouteParams` into my constructor for App, because it's not being created by the router.

So how do I get query params on load? Do I really need to have App create an empty component (AppRoot or something) for the sole purpose of having it contain a `router-outlet` just so i can flow it through the router? That seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead.. anyone know of a better way?

Comment: Have you tried to just add a custom instance to `bootstrap(..., provide(RouteParams, asValue: new RouteParams(...))`. Without trying I'd assume that the `RouteParams` are injected from the router if available, otherwise the ones from `bootstrap()` (not tried myself yet).

Comment: That works to provide an instance, but it doesn't see the param, its empty. I suspect because the params actually go to the Home route

Comment: I assumed you set the params on the passed instance, don't you do that?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand? I would expect them to get parsed from window.location?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. This won't work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that you can't do this, so I had to cheat. My bootstrap now loads App, which just loads a single Route;

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/...', component: RootView, as: 'RootView', useAsDefault: true}
])
export class App {
    constructor() {}
}
```

and then RootView can inject RouteParams as expected;

```
export class RootView {
    constructor(routeParams: RouteParams) {
    }
}
```

This still feels horribly inelegant to me, if anyone has a better way, please do comment!